# Reading array from render function by state management in react native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render array of data in form of card. However only one item will be render as single card at a time. Once user update card number, next item will be rendered. 
I am not able to call array item wise in render function.

map function for list doesn't work for me as it will populate whole array but I want user to input before next item.

This data is saved from API call

```
data = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Card #1', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535591273668-578e31182c4f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f28261f0564880c9086a57ee87a68887&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Card #2', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535576434247-e0f50b766399?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=232f6dbab45b3f3a6f97e638c27fded2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Card #3', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535565454739-863432ea3c0e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7edfb9bc7d214dbf2c920723cb0ffce2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
];
```

This is array of Data. Now from render function:

```
renderCard() {
    const buttons = ['Call', 'Fold', 'Raise']
    const selectedIndex = this.state.selectedIndex
    return (
      <Card
        title="Profiling Question "
        image={{ uri: this.state.data[selectedIndex].uri }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {this.state.data[selectedIndex].text}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.updateIndex}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

UpdateIndex function updates index value. This is working fine.

I expect single card to be rendered with button to update to next card.

**However I am getting this error:**

`TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluting'this.state.data[selectedIndex].uri')`

**EDIT:**

I have tried removing index too to check as below:

```
return (
      <Card
        title={"Question No: "+ this.state.selectedIndex +1 }
        image={{ uri: this.state.data[0].question_image }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {this.state.data[0].question_text}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.updateLn}>
          <Text> Update Question </Text>
        </Button>
      </Card>
    );
```

Still same error.

My state is as:

````
export default class QuizScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selectedIndex: 0,
      dataLength: 0,
      cardIndex: 0,
    };
    this.updateIndex = this.updateIndex.bind(this)
    this.updateLn = this.updateLn.bind(this)
  }```
````

Comment: can you show a screenshot of expected result?

Comment: `const { selectedIndex } = this.state` ??

Comment: You set array data in const and you trying to getting from state. recheck your code once

Comment: Sorry Typo in copying. Edited code in question again.

Comment: remove state in renderCard

Comment: did, still same error.

`const data = this.state.data
    const index = this.state.selectedIndex
    return (
      <Card
        title={"Question No: "+ this.state.selectedIndex +1 }
        image={{ uri: data[index] }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {data[index].question_text}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.updateLn}>
          <Text> Update Question </Text>
        </Button>
      </Card>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array rendering in React Native (undefined is not an object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831549/array-rendering-in-react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

I see a big mistake here

First you say that the selected index is the state

```
const selectedIndex = this.state
```

But after you get `data` from the state

```
image={{ uri: this.state.data[selectedIndex].uri }}
```

So `selectedIndex` isn't an array index, it will be some object like

```
{
    ...anyThing
    data = [...]
}
```

You can't use an object as a key to you array. This is why you are getting the error.

For us to help you in what you need, Please show us the rest of the code so we can understand better what is in your `this.state`.

Comment: Sorry Typo in copying. Edited code in question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data= [
  { id: 1, text: 'Card #1', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535591273668-578e31182c4f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f28261f0564880c9086a57ee87a68887&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Card #2', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535576434247-e0f50b766399?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=232f6dbab45b3f3a6f97e638c27fded2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Card #3', uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535565454739-863432ea3c0e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7edfb9bc7d214dbf2c920723cb0ffce2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60' },
];

renderCard() {
    const buttons = ['Call', 'Fold', 'Raise']
    const selectedIndex = this.state
    return (
      <Card
        title="Profiling Question "
        image={{ uri: this.data[selectedIndex].uri }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {this.data[selectedIndex].text}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.updateIndex}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

> ```
> you set data into const data array but retrieving from state data 
> output undefined
> replace with this.state.data[0].uri to this.data[0].uri
> ```

Comment: This was just to state data structure. Actual data is being called from API in json format.

Comment: replace with this.state.data[0].uri to this.data[0].uri

Comment: Not working as data is defined in const. I have updated question.