# Array rendering in React Native (undefined is not an object)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am rendering a array of data. It works fine with map function but if I try to call item wise it gives an error.
**Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[0].uri')**

This doesn't work

```
render () {
    const data  = this.state.data;
    const selectedIndex = this.state.selectedIndex;
    return (
      <View style={styles.text}>

            <Card
              title="Profiling Question "
              image={{ uri: data[0].uri }}
            >
              <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                {data[0].text}
              </Text>
              <Button
                onPress={this.updateIndex}
              />
            </Card>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

but this works fine:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.text}>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
            <Card
              title="Profiling Question "
              image={{ uri: item.question_image }}
            >
              <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                {item.question_text}
              </Text>
              <Button
                onPress={this.updateIndex}
              />
            </Card>
          )})}
      </View>
    );
```

I wish to render only ONE item at a time on screen. Once user clicks button then second item renders.

Comment: what is the initial value of `data[0]` ? are you making any api call to update it?

Comment: Yes i am ... during map it is updating correctly. In both cases, Api is made before render with componentWillmount

Comment: but that will be a async call, means rendering might happening before the success of that, so either hold the rendering of card until you didnt get the data or put the default value in the array. With map it is working because, map body will be executed only after you get the data, not before that, that why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for the empty value of data. if value is null or not set then display nothing otherwise display data.

```
render () {
    const data  = this.state.data;
    const selectedIndex = this.state.selectedIndex;
    return (
      <View style={styles.text}>

            <Card
              title="Profiling Question "
              image={{ uri: data[0] ? data[0].uri: null }}
            >
              <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                {data[0] ? data[0].text: ''}
              </Text>
              <Button
                onPress={this.updateIndex}
              />
            </Card>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can account for data being empty by using conditional rendering to make sure it is only rendered after data is filled

```
render() {
    const data          = this.state.data;
    const selectedIndex = this.state.selectedIndex;
    return (
        <View style={styles.text}>
            {data && data[selectedIndex] &&
            <Card
                title="Profiling Question "
                image={{uri: data[selectedIndex].question_image}}
            >
                <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                    {data[selectedIndex].question_text}
                </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.updateIndex}
                />
            </Card>
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```